# Redactor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

I'm trying to use [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) in my project. I want to add some text to the editor upon button click.

The API says you can do it like this:

```
function insertHtml()
{
    var html = '<h3>INSERTED</h3>';
    $('#redactor').redactor('insert.html', html);
}
```

Well, my code looks like this:

```
<button onclick="insertHtml();">Insert</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertHtml()
    {
        var html = '<h3>INSERTED</h3>';
        $('.redactor-box').redactor('insert.html', html);
    }
</script>
```

Redactor editor:

```
<div class="redactor-box">
<ul class="redactor-toolbar" id="redactor-toolbar-0" style=
"position: relative; width: auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
<li>
        <a class="re-icon re-bold" href="#" rel="bold" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-italic" href="#" rel="italic" tabindex=
        "-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-deleted" href="#" rel="deleted" tabindex=
        "-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-unorderedlist" href="#" rel="unorderedlist"
        tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-orderedlist" href="#" rel="orderedlist"
        tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-outdent" href="#" rel="outdent" tabindex=
        "-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-indent" href="#" rel="indent" tabindex=
        "-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-image" href="#" rel="image" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-file" href="#" rel="file" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-link" href="#" rel="link" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-horizontalrule" href="#" rel="horizontalrule"
        tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="re-icon re-mathematik redactor-btn-image" href="#" rel=
        "mathematik" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="redactor-editor redactor-placeholder" contenteditable="true"
dir="ltr" style="min-height: 300px;">
    <p>​</p>
</div>
<textarea class="redactor-box" cols="40" data-redactor-options=
"{&quot;lang&quot;: &quot;en&quot;, &quot;fileUpload&quot;: &quot;/redactor/upload/file/&quot;, &quot;imageUpload&quot;: &quot;/redactor/upload/image/&quot;}"
dir="ltr" id="id_body" name="body" placeholder="Vsebina vprašanja.." rows=
"10" style="display: none;">
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined(anonymous function) @ redactor.js:47n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n.fn.n.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2$.fn.redactor @ redactor.js:39insertHtml @ (index):366onclick @ (index):205
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's working if i use `#id_body` instead of  `.redactor-box`. Weird?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume it's because the example uses a jquery id lookup, which returns a single element, and your implementation is using a jquery class lookup which returns an array of elements.

Either use: `$('.redactor-box')[0]` or change the element's class in question to an id, and use `$('#redactor-box')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to init the redactor prior to calling the API methods

This should do the job:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.redactor-box').redactor();
  });

  function insertHtml() {
    var html = '<h3>INSERTED</h3>';
    $('.redactor-box').redactor('insert.html', html);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 elements in your markup having the same class `redactor-box`:

```
<div class="redactor-box">
```

and

```
<textarea class="redactor-box"
```

Try changing textarea's class to `redactor` and then calling Redactor API method on this class:

```
$('.redactor').redactor('insert.html', html);
```

However if you have several editors on 1 page then all of them will insert this html, so it's better to either use id or more specific class.

Also notice, that you can call Redactor API methods only after initializing Redactor, so you should first call:

```
$('.redactor').redactor();
```

(probably you did it already, mentioning it explicitly just in case)

Comment: @StarWars exactly this error is being thrown when redactor is not initialized. Read carefully my post - starting with `Also notice, that ...`

Comment: Solved it. I'm using redactor 10, using 'code.set' to set data worked.

Comment: @StarWars I'm using redactor 10.2.3 and before writing my comment I re-checked if the behavior is still the same as described in my post - it is. Anyway congratulations for solving your issue.